# Can I have a timer running during iOS 4.0+ multi-tasking?

Tags: iphone, ios4, timer, localnotification

So I have just managed to build a timer on my iOS app I'm working on, and it works great! Except for the fact that the whole point of the timer is to be able to multi-task with it.

Meaning, I want to be able to be in my app, set a timer, hit go, have it start ticking down to 0, and allow users to switch over to another app, and do that app until the timer hits 0, at which point a local notification will fire and alert them that time is up.

Currently I have the timer and the notifications bit figured out, but when I double tap the home button to multi-task away, the timer stops, and then when I return to it, it picks back up where it left off, as if I had never left...which defeats the purpose of the timer!!

Is it possible to have a timer run in the background with iOS 4.0?

Thanks

Comment: Check out: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a timer run in the background with iOS 4.0?

No.

However, you can schedule the local notification to fire at some predefined time in the future.